# Axios.delete is not working the way I want it too

Tags: javascript, express, axios

It's a gym app which when a user books themselves into a class, the class saves the userId as a user which will be attending, then also in the user model you also get the classes in which the user is attending too.

Currently hitting `500 (Internal Server Error)`.

These are the `axios` calls:

```
deleteClassHandler = () => {
    this.deleteUserClassHandler();
    const data = {
      userId: this.props.userId,
      classId: this.props.id
    }
    axios.delete('/api/classes/remove', data)
      .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
      });
}

deleteUserClassHandler = () => {
    const data = {
      userId: this.props.userId,
      classId: this.props.id
    }
    axios.delete('/api/auth/remove', data)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

The `this.props.userID` and `this.props.id` are populated fine with the right values.

**These are the routes -**

Classes routes:
`router.delete('/remove', ClassesController.deleteUser);`

Auth routes:
`router.delete('/remove', UserController.deleteClass);`

This are the controllers:

**Classes controller -**

```
exports.deleteUser = (req, res) => {
  console.log('cl userid ', req.body.userId);
  console.log('cl classid ', req.body.classId);
  GymClass.findById({
    _id: req.body.classId
  }, 'classMembers', (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('class up here');
      res.status(401).json({
        message: "Error Occured!"
      })
    } else {
      GymClass.findByIdAndDelete({
        "classMembers.userId" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.userId)
      }, (err) => {
        if(err) {
          console.log('class down');
            res.status(401).json({
              message: "Error Occured!"
            })
        } else {
          res.status(200).json({
            message: "Success!"
          })
        }
      });
    }
  })
}
```

**Auth controller -**

```
exports.deleteClass = (req, res) => {
  console.log('auth userid', req.body.userId);
  console.log('auth classid', req.body.classId);
  User.findById({
    _id: req.body.userId
  }, 'bookedClasses', (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('auth up here');
      res.status(401).json({
        message: "Error Occured!"
      })
    } else {
      GymClass.findByIdAndDelete({
        "bookedClasses.classId" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.classId)
      }, (err) => {
        if(err) {
          console.log('auth down here');
            res.status(401).json({
              message: "Error Occured!"
            })
        } else {
          res.status(200).json({
            message: "Success!"
          })
        }
      });
    }
  })
}
```

I am by no means a backend superstar and I have hit a brick wall with this one, does anyone here know how I could maybe possibly change the code and the way I am tackling this? Any issues spotted? **I have got a 500 server error** and I am not sure what to do. I can always post the two models for the user and classes if needed.

**This was also something I tried but did not work -**

```
axios.delete('/api/classes/remove', {
        data: {
          userId: this.props.userId,
          classId: this.props.id
        }
      })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to have your data in the config object axios.delete('someURL', { data: { userId: this.userId, classId: this.class.id}}) The delete method doesn't have a dedicated data parameter like PUT, PATCH, and POST. axios.delete(url, config) opposed to axios.post(url, data, config)

Comment: @Budhead2004 That is what I was reading but I still struggled to put it into my code, so which way would you tackle it? I was thinking of making it a `PUT` and deleting it via that but I did not think that was the right way so I didn't do it. How would you work around it?

Comment: Maybe you wan to put it into the uri as param, sth like `/api/users/:userId/classes/:classId`. Also `/remove` is redundant, since in a RESTful call, the method `DELETE` is already hinting its use